# Console of Dev Tools in Excel for Windows

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ms-office, office-js

I have created an Excel add-in with AngularJS. I use `<div ng-show="isLoggedIn">...</div>` and `<div ng-show="!isLoggedIn">...</div>` to control different contents according to `$scope.isLoggedIn`.

It works fine in Excel online, whereas when I test it in Excel 2016 for Windows, it does not work well as follows.

In general, does anyone know how to debug this? is it possible to open Dev Tools to see the console like what we do in Excel Online?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the latest builds of Office 2016 & Visual Studio 2015 or 2017 installed, you will have an "Attach Debugger" option on the personality menu (the left arrow at the top right of the task pane).

If you don't have VS but are running Windows 10, you can use the F12 Tool Chooser that's located at C:\Windows\SysWOW64\F12\F12Chooser.exe to attach.  More details can be found here: https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10

Comment: Thank you, do you know how to launch the F12 Tool in Excel for Windows 7?

Comment: I believe that this is only a feature on Win10.